# Proofs based on convexity for quadratic functions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratics

I have attempted to proof the following, based on the given data:

Let $f(x)= x^{T}Ax +2b^{T}x + c$, where $A\in\mathbb R$  symmetric matrix, $b\in\mathbb R$ and $c\in\mathbb R$. Then:

i) $x$ is critical point iff $Ax=-b$

ii) If $A\geq 0$, then x is a global minimum iff $Ax=-b$

iii) If $A > 0$, then $x=-A^{-1}b$ is a strict global minimum.

My attempt:

Let $Q(x)=x^{T}Ax$.

By definition of convex, for any $x,y\in\mathbb R$, we have $$Q(\frac{x+y}2)\leq\frac12(Q(x)+Q(y))$$
Thus it is sufficient to reduce and prove that
$$\frac12(x+y)^TA(x+y)\leq x^TAx+y^TAy\\
x^TAy+y^TAx\leq x^TAx+y^TAy$$
Namely
$$(x-y)^TA(x-y)\geq0$$
which is directly followed by positive semi-definite.

$f(x) = Q(x) + 2b^{T}x+c$, hence $f$ convex as sum of convex functions.

i) Let $x$ be a critical point. By definition of critical point, $x$ satisfies $\nabla f(x) = 0 $. Therefore, $\nabla f(x)=2x^{T}A^{T} + 2b = 0 => Ax=-b$. For the other direction, if $Ax=-b => x=-A^{-1}b$, substituting in the $f$ equation  I derive $\nabla f(x)=0$ so $x$ is a critical point.

ii) Let $x$ a global minimum. Then  $x$ satisfies $\nabla f(x) = 0 => \nabla f(x) = 2x^{T}A^{T} + 2b =0 => Ax=-b$ . For the other direction, let $Ax=-b$, then $f(x)= bx+c$. A linear function which is convex and which implies that every local minimum is a global minimum. But it seems I don't have enough data to derive that an optimal solution even exists.

iii) If $A>0$ then $f$ is strictly convex. By first order characterization of strict convexity,

$f(y)> f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x) \forall x, y \in dom(f), x \neq y$ (1) .

If $x=-A^{-1}b$ then by substituting x to the right side of (1) I derive:

$f(y)>-b^{2}A^{-1}+c$. But it fails to show how $x$ is a global minimum.

Any help or opinion on how to prove i), ii), iii) is welcome

Answer (score 2):

Any symmetric real matrix $H$   is related to an infinite number of diagonal matrices. There are algorithms for simply producing such, see [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

In what follows note $PQ=QP = I.$ If the original $H$ is positive semi-definite, the diagonal $d_{ii}$ elements of $D$ all have $d_{ii} \geq 0.$  If positive definite, we have the stronger $d_{ii} > 0.$ This is Sylvester's Law of Inertia.
In either case, there is an additional nonsingular diagonal matrix $E$ such that $D_{1} = E^T P^T H P E$  is diagonal, with some $r$ initial diagonal elements equal to $1,$ the remainder $0.$ Here the rank $r$ has $r < n$  if semidefinite, while $r=n$ and $D_1=I$ when positive definite. Take $U = PE,$  we have invertible real $U$ with $U^T H U = D_1$ The point is that we can take $V = U^{-1}$ and $H = V^T D_1 V.$ When $D_1$ is the identity, we just have $H = V^T V.$  This sort of thing is sometimes called a Cholesky decomposition. When $D_1$ has one or more zero elements on the diagonal, we can replace them by 1's as long as we trim the matching columns of
$V,$   call that $V_2.$ In that case $H = V_2^T V_2.$

It seems your original expression had $2 b^T x,$ the we do not need the $1/2.$

You can use this decomposition to complete the square in your expression. Suppose we just say  $$ A = V^T V.  $$ Then
$$ \color{red}{ (x^T V^T +  b^T )     ( Vx +  b)  + ( c - b \cdot b) \; \; =  \; \; ( Vx +  b)^T  ( Vx +  b) + (c - b \cdot b)}$$ is your expression. It is just the dot product of $( Vx +  b)$ with itself added to $(c - b \cdot b)$  and is always at least $(c - b \cdot b).$

Note that $b^T x = x^T b = b \cdot x$ is just a number, the ordinary dot product. One thing to remember is that a 1 by 1 matrix is just a single number, and is its own transpose.

When $A$ is invertible, there does exist an $x_0$ with $A x_0 + b = 0.$ When $A$ is singular, there might be such an $x_0$ and there might not.

Editing is very slow on my computer today.
When there is an $A x_0 + b =0$  take $x = x_0 + t v,$
where $t$ is a scalar variable  and $v$ is any vector. When there is no such $x_0,$  call the current vector $x_1$   ans switch to $x=x_1 + t v.$ If needed, one may take ordinary first and second derivatives by the single variable $t.$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 &  - 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
4 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand the Cholesky decomposition you used, but not the red part. Where do you think that should be applied? I tried some calculations based on the red part but cannot derive a result of the type $f(y)>-A^{-1}b, \forall y$ where $x=-A^{-1}b$, that will result in x being a global minimum on part iii). My apologies if I am not understanding